# I want to create an enemy AI behavior for a sniper enemy type in Monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have already implemented a basic follow player behavior for a different enemy

```
    // For knife soldier, simply runs at player
    IEnumerable<int> FollowPlayer(float acceleration = 0.3f)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!PlayerShip.Instance.IsDead)
                Velocity += (PlayerShip.Instance.Position - Position) * (acceleration / (PlayerShip.Instance.Position - Position).Length());

            if (Velocity != Vector2.Zero)
                Orientation = PlayerShip.Instance.Position.ToAngle();

            yield return 0;
        }
    }`
```

I want to implement a more complex behavior for a sniper. It will act on the premise that the sniper must be a certain distance from the player before it can shoot.
Here is the code for that:

```
public static void HandleSniperShotRange()
    {
        float acceleration = 0.2f;
        // Check whether player is within sniper range (Used for sniper behaviour)
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
        {

            if (enemies[i].IsActive && IsCollidingSniperRange(PlayerShip.Instance, enemies[i]))
            {
                enemies[i].Velocity += (PlayerShip.Instance.Position - enemies[i].Position) * (acceleration / (PlayerShip.Instance.Position - enemies[i].Position).Length());
                enemies[i].Orientation = PlayerShip.Instance.Position.ToAngle() * -1;

            }
        }

    }



private static bool IsCollidingSniperRange(Entity a, Entity b)
    {
        float radius = a.Radius + b.Radius + 120;
        return !a.IsExpired && !b.IsExpired && Vector2.DistanceSquared(a.Position, b.Position) < radius * radius;
    }
```

My code currently will draw a sniper to the screen but it will not move.

Now I was not able to put them both in the same Enemy class as my EntityManager class stores the lists of all added enemy entities. When I did put the sniper behavior in the enemy class it would work but all enemies would retreat from the player if one was too close.

How could I either put this code into my Enemy class or how could I leave it in the EntityManager but get it to update each frame and interact correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understood this correctly your issue is how to handle different EnemyClasses in one ManagerClass?

You usually have a Base-Enemy Class (can be an interface as well if you dont define logic there) which provides basic behaviour. On top of that you define specific enemy types. 
Your manager class just handles some kind of enemy list while the logic is held in the specific enemy class.
Which is a simple example of inheritance and polymorphism...

Pseudo Code:

```
interface IEnemy
{
    void FollowPlayer();
}

class EnemySniper : IEnemy
{
    void FollowPlayer()
    {
        //Implement Followig Player Logic for Sniper
    }

}

class EnemyManager
{
    List<IEnemy> enemies = new List<IEnemy>();
    //Add all your enemies at gamestart or wherever

    foreach(IEnemy ie in enemies) //this needs to be called on each Update()
        ie.FollowPlayer();
}
```